# Как один сетевой сокет разбить на два?

Tags: linux, c, сокет

Ситуация такая:
Клиент соединен с сервером по протоколу tcp, однако это одно соединение, а мне нужно чтобы во время работы программы клиента количество соединений менялось. Допустим я хочу одновременно в разных потоках отправлять данные на сервер и также одновременно принимать другие данные от сервера, клиентов много, поэтому просто создавать новое соединение в основном сокете не вариант, новое соединение должно иметь те же характеристики что и старо, как на сервере так и на клиенте.

Дано:
установленное соединение с серверов(сокет)

Найти: Разбить это одно соединение на множество других

Решение: ???

Comment: Это невозможно. Просто посмотрите на [формат сетевых пакетов](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/exploring-the-anatomy-of-a-data-packet/). Там нет места для идентификации программы (потока). Поэтому вам остается для новых потоков лишь создавать обычным способом новые соединения

Comment: @avp ну тут Вы не правы, в в заголовке места нет, но есть неограниченное место в теле.

Comment: @eri, ядро ничего не знает о теле, соответственно (если не брать [SCTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP)) всю реализацию протокола придется делать самому на прикладном уровне со всеми вытекающими издержками (ТС пишет *`"новое соединение должно иметь те же характеристики что и старо, как на сервере так и на клиенте"`*) и ограничениями

Comment: протокол на прикладном уровне это плохо?

Comment: да и цитата противоречит тому что написанно на пару слов раньше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство программ при такой задаче используют реализацию протокола на прикладном уровне.

Самый простой и самый распространенный - это разбить поток на TLV структуры. Расшифровывается как Тип, Длинна, Данные.

Несколько потоков данных режутся на буферы. В сокет записывается тип, длинна буфера и сам буфер. На другой стороне: read(1) - switch case - l=ntoa(read(2)) - read(l) собирются в  разные потоки.